# Choice of plural and singular, definite and indefinite articles for multiple nouns

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Which of the following is correct?

1. There are apple and orange.
2. There is an apple and an orange.
3. There are an apple and an orange.
4. There are apple and orange.

Comment: Well, to start, 1 and 4 are duplicates. Beyond that, there is insufficient context to give a definitive answer to the question, as one can imagine a context in which each is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is an apple and an orange.

We can't say "there are an apple and orange" because we are referring each of them as a single two different fruits not as a whole. So we can't say "are". but if you refer them as a whole for ex : "there are fruits" it is correct or if there are more than one in each specific fruit ex: "there are apples and oranges" is correct.